# Using newcommands inside tikzpicture foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm attempting to nest commands in my TikZ pages so that I can make progressively more complicated things with small bits of code at each level.  The code I have so far is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\newcommand{\drawSquare}[3]{%
  \draw[thick,#3] (#1-0.5,#2-0.5) rectangle (#1+0.5,#2+0.5);}
\newcommand{\boxesAtHeight}[3]{%
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
    \drawSquare{\i}{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \boxesAtHeight{4}{0}{black}
  \boxesAtHeight{2}{1}{black}
  \boxesAtHeight{1}{2}{black}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I use sharelatex, and when I try to compile, I get 4 errors. On the line after `\end{tikzpicture}`, I have the error

> Paragraph ended before `\pgffor@next` was complete.

On the line of `\end{document}`, I get the three errors

> Missing `\endgroup` inserted.
>
> Missing `}` inserted.
>
> LaTeX error: `\begin{tikzpicture}` on input line 12 ended by `\end{document}`.

When I replace the code within the `tikzpicture` by expanding the `\boxesAtHeight` macro, I get the same errors.

When I further expand the `\drawSquare` macro, I get the following output

[image: successful output after expanding every macro]

To be clear, the first expansion resulted in the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \drawSquare{\i}{0}{black}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,2}
    \drawSquare{\i}{1}{black}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,1}
    \drawSquare{\i}{2}{black}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And the second expansion resulted in the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
    \draw[thick,black] (\i-0.5,0-0.5) rectangle (\i+0.5,0+0.5);
  \foreach \i in {1,...,2}
    \draw[thick,black] (\i-0.5,1-0.5) rectangle (\i+0.5,1+0.5);
  \foreach \i in {1,...,1}
    \draw[thick,black] (\i-0.5,2-0.5) rectangle (\i+0.5,2+0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Can anyone explain to me why I'm getting errors?  I know that the `\drawSquare` macro works outside of loops.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It looks like you are drawing Young tableaux, if so, have you had a look at [`ytableau`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ytableau)?

Comment: @JP-Ellis, I believe `ytableau` will work for this particular project, thanks!  I'll use `ytableau` for this project, but I also hope someone can answer my question so I can have it work in the future when I'm making other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group the body of the for loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\newcommand{\drawSquare}[3]{%
  \draw[thick,#3] (#1-0.5,#2-0.5) rectangle (#1+0.5,#2+0.5);}
\newcommand{\boxesAtHeight}[3]{%
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}
    {\drawSquare{\i}{#2}{#3}}}%<== put the \drawSquare{\i}{#2}{#3} in {}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \boxesAtHeight{4}{0}{black}
  \boxesAtHeight{2}{1}{black}
  \boxesAtHeight{1}{2}{black}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]